# FOSRestBundle and Pagerfanta

Tags: symfony, symfony4, fosrestbundle, pagerfanta

I'm trying to paginate a result with Pagerfanta

My Controller:

```
    /**
     * @Rest\Get(
     *     path="/users",
     *     name="get_users",
     * )
     *
     * @return View
     */
    public function users()
    {
        $pagers = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository(User::class)
            ->findAllWithPagination(10, 1);

        return $this->view($pagers->getCurrentPageResults(), Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
```

My UserRepository:

```
/**
 * @param int $limit
 * @param int $offset
 * @return Pagerfanta
 */
public function findAllWithPagination(int $limit = 10, int $offset = 1): Pagerfanta
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->select('u')
    ;

    return $this->paginate($qb, $limit, $offset);
}

/**
 * @param QueryBuilder $qb
 * @param int $limit
 * @param int $offset
 * @return Pagerfanta
 */
protected function paginate(QueryBuilder $qb, int $limit = 10, int $offset = 1): Pagerfanta
{
    if (0 == $limit || 0 == $offset) {
        throw new \LogicException('$limit & $offset must be greater than 0.');
    }

    $pager = new Pagerfanta(new DoctrineORMAdapter($qb));
    $currentPage = ceil($offset + 1) / $limit;
    $pager->setCurrentPage($currentPage);
    $pager->setMaxPerPage($limit);

    return $pager;
}
```

I don't understand why I have a 404 response when I'm trying to access this resource. What did I do wrong?

> "message": "Page Not Found",
>                   "class": "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException",
>   "file":
>   "/var/www/html/model-backend/vendor/white-october/pagerfanta-bundle/EventListener/ConvertNotValidCurrentPageToNotFoundListener.php",

Comment: It seems that the current page is not valid. Your current page is 0.1 not 1 you should fix the `ceil($offset + 1) / $limit; ` I think becaus eyou are mading an api, so you shoud get the current page from the request query like that `$request->query->get('page', 1);` then you call a function ` $pagerfanta->setCurrentPage($page);`.